# What is the recomended way to pass Blazor parameters that include special characters between pages

Tags: asp.net, blazor

I have a target page that accepts a parameter like this...

```
@page "/LocationDetailPopup/{placename}"
@code{
[Parameter]
public string placename { get; set; }
```

}

and I provide to link to it from the source page like this...

```
 <a href="/LocationDetailPopup/@Uri.EscapeDataString(place)"> more info...</a>
```

This works fine when navigating internally, even when *place* is actually a string such as *"38.7650,-90.3540"*.  This generates a URI like this...

> https://..mydomain.../locationdetailpopup/38.7650%2C-90.3540

However, if I save the URI of the target page and paste it into another browser tab I get a 404 error when *place* contains a hyphen or period.  (It works fine if *place* is a string such as "Joes Diner".) I also get a 404 error if I manually edit the URI to escape the hyphen and period, i.e.

> https://..mydomain.../locationdetailpopup/38%2E7650%2C%2D90%2E3540

I can work around this by implementing my own escape/unescape mechanism on the source and target but it seems there ought to be an easier way of safely passing parameters in way that allows them to be used in permalinks.  It looks like [UriHelper.BuildRelative](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.extensions.urihelper.buildrelative?view=aspnetcore-3.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_Extensions_UriHelper_BuildRelative_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_PathString_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_PathString_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_QueryString_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_FragmentString_) ought to be of use here but I haven't been able to work out the correct way to use it.

Just to be clear, I am looking for a way to *generate* a URI containing an arbitrary parameter that can be safely used both as an internal link and as an external permalink without triggering the 404 error.

Answer (score -2):

you can use QueryHelpers

```
 <a href="/LocationDetailPopup?test=@Uri.EscapeDataString(place)"> more info...</a>

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
if (QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(uri.Query).TryGetValue("test", out var testfromUrl))
        {
            test= testfromUrl.First();

        }
}
```

Comment: Hmm - maybe I am misunderstanding but that doesn't really address the question. What I want to know is how to ensure the _generated_ URI is correctly formatted so as to avoid the 404 error when it is used from an external source.  I've added a clarification to the original question.

Comment: You need to explain your solution.